# Can I have the time of an object from its creation or instance?

Tags: java

I have a code where a Student Object is created and depending on its time has to move from one list to another, therefore I need to timestamp those objects to know when they were created

Comment: 1. question is not very clear 2. show us what you have tried.

Comment: Are you sure you want this? I mean, what bearing does the creation time of the `Student` object have on it? If it was loaded from the database 3 minutes later would it be any different? It seems like this is information that belongs in a different class.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Student
{
    private Date creationDate = new Date();

    public Date getCreationDate()
    {
        return new Date(creationDate.getTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for safe publishing of created date (yikes - Date is mutable!)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an instance variable with the current time in the constructor.

The code that created it can then interrogate the new instance and move it to the appropriate list.

If the creation time only matters once, don't even use an instance variable, just get the current time when you create it and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

System.currentTimeMillis() returns the current time in milliseconds.